# Uploading files to server in the same folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, server

I want to add `mp3, lrc, wav, txt` to the server and the folder name would be `title` and all of the extensions mentioned above would have specified names. As seen in the code, the mp3 would be `"vocal.mp3"`.

```
addSong(event) {

    jQuery('#addItemSave').text("Please wait!");

    this._service.addSong(this.authorText, this.titleText, this.durationText, this.genre).subscribe(
        res => {
            this.data.push(res.data[0]);
            this.addSongFilesToServer();
    });
}

private addSongFilesToServer() {
    this._service.addSongFilesToServer(this.titleText,
            this.mp3file, this.lrcfile, this.pitchfile, this.thumbfile).subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log("Done! Now hide loading icon or what ever...");
            jQuery('#addItemSave').text("Save");
            jQuery('#addNewSongDialog').modal('hide');
            jQuery('#addNewSongDialog').find("input,textarea,select")
                    .val('')
                    .end()
                .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]")
                    .prop("checked", "")
                    .end();
    });
}

addSongFilesToServer(title, mp3, lrc, txt, thumb) {
    let url = this._config.ServerWithApiUrl + "uploadFiles";
    let body : FormData = new FormData();
    body.append('mp3', mp3, "vocal.mp3");
    body.append('txt', txt, "pitches.txt");
    body.append('lrc', lrc, "lyric.lrc");
    body.append('thumb', thumb, "thumbnail.png");
    body.append('title', title);
    this._config.headers.delete('Content-Type');

    return this._http.post(url, body, { headers: this._config.headers })
        .map(res => res.json()).catch(function(err){
            throw err;
    });
}
```

`addSong(event)` is called when a button is pressed on the page and the all of the files that need to be passed on, are being passed on. The only problem here is that `mp3, lrc, wav, txt` go all under different folders with their their, for example `vocal.mp3`.

Just to illustrate, this is what I am getting at the moment :

```
├───songs
│   ├───vocal
│   │    vocal.mp3
│   ├───pitches
│   │    pitches.txt
...
```

And this is what I need:

```
├───songs
│   ├───title
│   │    vocal.mp3
│   │    lyric.lrc
│   │    pitches.txt
...
```

Comment: You should not do that. Instead, you should store your data in either your database, or on your API server.

Comment: My other code Is built around that so I pretty much need to do it that way.

Comment: Well you can't. Angular runs on the user's computer, and you need to write on your server.

Comment: My bad, I didn't read your question correctly. This isn't an Angular question, this is a server question. Identify your server language and change the tags accordingly. In the meantime, I'm going to edit your post a bit to avoid confusion like I just did.

Comment: Done. Now, all you have to do left is post the code of your server and change the tags accordingly. Since it depends on both your API calls and your server endpoints, you can leave the angular tag on, but if you don't add other tags, you won't get that much help ...

Comment: @trichetriche I am sorry that I did not answer earlier, but I have not done this project completely and I do not quite know which is the `server code`. How can I find it?

Comment: And also I mean, since it is already adding to the server isn't the code I provided everything that is needed?

Comment: not really : what angular does is sending the file to your API. The name, location, type, and everything related to the file, is handled by your API. You can send file `1.txt` from Angular and save it as `beautifulGirl.jpeg` in your backend : that's up to your backend to do that. And by server code I mean the code used for the api : it can be Java, node, golang, php ... This is called the backend, it handles an API which serves endpoints. Try asking around if someone can answer you.

Comment: @trichetriche I am alone at the moment, but is this what is needed?

Comment: I can assure you, you won't be able to resolve that in Angular.

Comment: By asking "is this what is needed" i meant if the server code I had added will suffice.

Comment: Didn't see sorry ! That's exactly it, the uploadFiles method is registering the files in songs/. Since your question won't be on top, I suggest you make a new one with the nodeJS tag and ask to change the save location of the files

Comment: (you can also do it yourself, it's JS after all)

Comment: Thank you a lot..

Comment: No problem, that's why I'm here !